# UIDocumentInteractionController file isn't attached to Mail if there's another application supporting the file type

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uidocumentinteraction

I'm opening the `.stl` file on iOS using `UIDocumentInteractionController`. I see the following options:

[image]

Now if I choose Mail it'll automatically attach .stl file to the email. That's ok.

But if I have another application supporting `.stl` files installed (for ex. MeshLab), then I see the following:

[image]

And if I choose Mail again - it won't attach the file to an email anymore.

Why is it so (why the file isn't attached to an email in second case)? Is there a way to change that behavior?

P.S. I'm using Xamarin.iOS, but don't think it matters in this case.

Comment: this dialog could be seen inside the Mail app itself (when opening attached files). There's the same behavior there

Comment: However, for some extensions this isn't true. For example - .zip files are attached correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I found I was not providing the MIME type in the Export Type declaration. See bottom of here:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.text</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Field Note Keywords</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.neukadye.customUTIHandler.keywords</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>keywords</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/json</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```